# How to generate legacy receiving address in Bitcoin core 0.19.x.x

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness, bech32-address, p2pkh

I must have missed the memo.  I see Bitcoin Core 19.1.0.1 defaults to generating Bech32 receive addresses (prefixed with "bc1"), and offers a checkmark to generate P2SH addresses instead (prefixed with "3").

But if I want to generate the legacy P2PKH addresses I know and love (prefixed with "1"), it seems I need to drop into the console and run something like:

`getnewaddress("mylabel","legacy")`

Is there a way to do that in the GUI?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There’s no option for it in the GUI because it’s largely to your detriment to use non-segwit transaction types at this point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From within the GUI, no, and this is intentional. There is no reason to use P2PKH addresses anymore. If you need backwards compatibility, then that's what the P2SH checkbox is for.

But if you really must have P2PKH addresses, you can configure Bitcoin Core to only use them by adding `addresstype=legacy` to your bitcoin.conf file. If you want your change to also be P2PKH, you will need to set `changetype=legacy` as well.